# MailNickname Attribute in EntraId

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-entra-id

we are currently developing a tool that automatically creates entra id security groups. In order to create a security group the mailNickname attribute has to be set. Since this attribute has different requirements from the displayName we can't just set the displayName as the mailNickname.

So the question is what is this attribute used for? I know that it has relevance in M365 groups but I am unable to find anything regarding security groups.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: **`MailNickName`** is the required parameter to create groups in Microsoft Entra ID.

To create the security group **without mail enabled**, you can make use of below command:

```
Connect-AzureAD

New-AzureADGroup -DisplayName "TestRukSecurityGroup" -SecurityEnabled $true -Description "Test Ruk security group"  -MailEnabled $false -MailNickName "NotSet"
```

[image]

**Security group created successfully without setting `MailNickName`**:

[image]

[image]

If you want to **create mail enabled security group**, then make us of Exchange online module:

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline

New-DistributionGroup -Name "MailEnabledSecurityGrp" -Alias "MailEnabledSecurityGrp" -Type "Security"
```

[image]

**Mail enabled security group created successfully:**

[image]

[image]

**Security groups** can be mail-enabled also, they can be used for email communication too.

- The primary purpose of security group is for access control that is grant or deny access to resources.
- Email enabled security group has security-related functionality and email distribution capabilities.
- Email enabled security groups can be used to receive and send email messages and is used as a mailing list.

*Based on your requirement you can create either security group or mail enabled security group.*

**References:**

[Create Security Group and Add Members in Azure AD using PowerShell)](https://morgantechspace.com/2021/12/create-security-group-and-add-members-in-azure-ad-using-powershell.html) by Morgan

[How to manage email enabled groups](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-where-manage-email-enabled-groups-valentin-komarovskiy-mba#:%7E:text=Security%20Groups%3A&text=They%20are%20security%2Denabled%2C%20which,purpose%20is%20for%20access%20control.) by Valentin Komarovskiy

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, however I still don't know why a mailnickname is required for a non mail enabled security group, do you have any insights on this?

Comment: By default it's required but you can set it to not set like I shown in the first command

Comment: Okay so no one knows why it is required? Does "NotSet" do something different than just putting anything else in there?

Comment: Not set will not enabled mail for the security group

Comment: The creation of group command requires mailnickname parameter and it's mandatory

Comment: Some of the Powershell commands have mandatory parameters and mailnickname is one of them

Comment: I understand all that but I want a explanation what this is used for. "Not set will not enabled mail for the security group" is pretty surely wrong as you also have to set the MailEnabled boolean when creating a group.

Comment: Mail enabled must be set to false